# Cannot Drop Subscription from PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm using pgAdmin and can't delete the subscriptions in the database or drop the database.

When I attempt to drop the database I receive the error message

```
ERROR: database "xxxx" is being used by logical replication subscription DETAIL: There are 4 subscriptions.
```

When I attempt to drop the subscriptions I receive

```
ERROR: could not drop the replication slot "xxxx" on publisher DETAIL: The error was: ERROR: replication slot "xxxx" does not exist
```

I receive 0 results when querying for replication slots

```
select * from pg_replication_slots
```

When I query for subscriptions they all show up

```
SELECT * FROM pg_subscription
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you have to go through this elaborate dance:

```
alter subscription <sub1> disable;
alter subscription <sub1> set (slot_name = none);
drop subscription <sub1>;
```

for each subscription, before you can drop the database.

I think the justification for this monstrosity is they want to make it really hard to drop a subscription without also dropping the slot it services on the publisher.  You can do it, you just have to go two steps out of your way, for each subscription.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Still getting - "ERROR:  subscription "subtest" does not exist" even though it's showing in pgAdmin.

Comment: @BlabzX Sounds like you are connected to the wrong database/system in one of your sessions.

Comment: maybe your are not connected to the database : `\c xxxx`

Comment: Try command "\dRs" to show subscription in current connected database.  Some replication tables are unique for every database server instance and therefore select on these tables can return values for other unconnected databases.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. Connect to the database

```
psql your_db;
```

and then

```
drop subscription my_subscription;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Connect to the subscriber database

### Disable the pglogical subscription

```
select pglogical.alter_subscription_disable('SUBSCRIPTION_NAME');
```

### Drop the pglogical subscription

```
select pglogical.drop_subscription('SUBSCRIPTION_NAME', true)
```

### References :

https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources-old/pglogical/pglogical-docs/